# Manipulating arrays with recursive function

Tags: ruby

```
def rps_tournament_winner(tournament)
  for i in 0..1 do
    if tournament[i][1].is_a? Array then
      rps_tournament_winner(tournament[i])
    else 
      tournament=rps_game_winner(tournament)
      return
    end
  end
  return tournament
end
```

This is a part of rock-papers-scissors implementation in Ruby

```
rps_game_winner
```

takes an array of two arrays in format of

```
[ ["Allen", "S"], ["Omer", "P"] ]
```

where first element is player's name, second element is their decision and returns the winner.

```
rps_tournament_winner
```

takes an input of nested arrays with arbitrary depth like

```
[
  [
    [ ["Armando", "P"], ["Dave", "S"] ],
    [ ["Richard", "R"], ["Michael", "S"] ],
  ],
  [
    [ ["Allen", "S"], ["Omer", "P"] ],
    [ ["David E.", "R"], ["Richard X.", "P"] ]
  ]
]
```

What I am trying to do is modifying the original input as the function makes progress but the input comes out as it came in. Incorporating global variables are a solution but this is a work to be graded with an auto grader and I suspect it is just going to push some input directly to the function and compare the output so its not an option.

Comment: @NiklasB. Of course, since this is Ruby, it's impossible *not* to use objects `;)`. (I assume you mean classes, I'm just being pedantic.)

Comment: @Andrew: Oh, of course I meant objects with types sensible for the purpose ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several problems with your original code:

- You mix iteration with recursion
- You throw away the result of the recursion (`rps_tournament_winner(tournament[i])`)
- You don't return anything useful (`return` simply returns `nil`, but it doesn't matter, because you don't use the result anyways)

A fixed version using the original logic would be:

```
def rps_tournament_winner(tournament)
  result = []
  for i in 0..1 do
    if tournament[i][0][0].is_a? Array then
      result << rps_tournament_winner(tournament[i])
    else
      result << rps_game_winner(tournament[i])
    end
  end
  return result    
end
```

But actually that's equivalent to a simple

```
def rps_tournament_winner(tournament)
  if tournament[0][0].is_a? String
    rps_game_winner(tournament)
  else
    tournament.map { |t| rps_tournament_winner(t) }
  end
end
```

And it would be so much nicer using objects:

```
class Game < Struct.new(:player1, :choice1, :player2, :choice2)
  def winner
    'PRSP'.include?(choice1 + choice2) ? player1 : player2
  end
end

def rps_tournament_winner(tourn)
  return tourn.winner if tourn.is_a? Game
  tourn.map { |t| rps_tournament_winner(t) }
end
```

Comment: IMHO re-using the same variable name in the block as outside is not the best way to teach a new user :)

Comment: @Phrogz: Yeah, I guess the actual problem is that I used a one-letter argument name :P fixed.

Comment: I think an actual if/else statement would be better than the one line conditional early return (especially since the method is so short). Yes, it'd be two more lines, but I think it reads better.

Comment: @NiklasB. Coming from C/C++ it makes me think the second line will never execute because by brain jumps over the `if`. Probably because I rarely use the `return` keyword at all in Ruby and it puts me in a different parsing mode.

Comment: @Andrew: I don't like `if/else` constructs spanning a whole method, especially in cases like this where it's just an edge condition to check for. I also do this in C: Check and return early on special conditions like edge conditions of recursions or invalid arguments. It's a matter of taste, IMO. As a Perl programmer, this would surely feel a lot easier on the eyes :)

Comment: @NiklasB. Perhaps a ternary makes more sense then? Though that makes the line a bit long/dense. Oh well, it's all style opinion anyway `:)`

Comment: I am fairly inexperienced ruby, with my limited knowledge I only managed to come up with this, but I need further elaboration regarding the algorithm:

* Whats wrong with mixing iteration with recursion?
* That premature return statement just for "popping" purposes. What I am expecting from recursion is just modify the array and be done with it
*And again, the function is supposed to modify the array and return the modified array. Actually I just realised this is stupid :) But nevertheless you pretty much understood my idea.

Comment: @user1245989: Actually the iteration/recursion part was not quite correct. In fact you *need* to mix both to get a good result here :) The real problem is that you manipulate the given array, instead of creating a new one. In Ruby and actually in all other languages as well, it's good style to never change a given argument, but instead create a new structure based on the given one and return it. In this case, my code creates a new array based on the old one using `[]` and `<<`. The `map` method does the exact same thing: Iterate over the array and build a new one.

Answer (score 3):

Your recursive solution should keep choosing winners unless the final winner is decided. [Niklas's second solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9540934/853005) stops at when the first level winners are decided. It should be refined as follows:

```
def rps_tournament_winner(tournament)
    if(tournament[0][0].is_a? String)
        rps_game_winner(tournament)
    else
        rps_tournament_winner(
            [rps_tournament_winner(tournament[0]),
            rps_tournament_winner(tournament[1])]
        )
    end
end
```

Comment: This is a much better solution

Answer (score 1):

The following function can also be a solution to manipulate arrays with a recursive function:

```
def rps_tournament_winner(tournament)
    while not tournament[0].is_a? String do
        i = i == 0 ? 1 : 0
        if tournament[i][0].is_a? String
            return rps_game_winner(tournament)
        else
            tournament[i] = rps_tournament_winner(tournament[i])
        end
    end
    return tournament
end
```